# Solution in $H^2 \cap H^{1}_{0}$

Tags: functional-analysis, elliptic-equations

Consider the following problem:
$$-\Delta \phi + \Delta^2 \phi = 4\pi u^2, \ \Omega$$
$$ \Delta \phi = 0, \partial \Omega$$
$$\phi = 0, \partial\Omega$$
How can I prove that the space of weak solutions of this problem is $H^2\cap H^{1}_0(\Omega)$?

It's clear for me that $\phi \in H^1_0$, but why $\Delta \phi = 0$ leads to the space $H^2\cap H^{1}_0(\Omega)$?

Comment: How do you define a weak solution for this problem?

Comment: A weak solution for this problem is defined via the equation
$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla \phi \nabla v + \int_{\Omega}\Delta \phi \Delta v = \int_{\Omega}4\pi u^2v,$$
for $v$ test function.

Comment: And what is the function space for the test and trial function? (At the end, I think that your question boils down to regularity of solutions of Poisson's equation)

Comment: Can be the space $C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$?

Comment: If your solution belongs to $C_c^\infty$, it is also in $H^2$. However, in this space you will not get existence of solutions...

Comment: I think I don't understood.The space of weak solutions for the problem is $H^{2}\cap H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$. The characterization of $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ give me functions that is null in frontier. But the problem involves de bi-laplacian, what brings me to the space $H^2(\Omega)$. So why the intersection of the spaces is the adequate space for the weak solutions?

Comment: So your question is why $H^2 \cap H_0^1$ is used as the solution space?

Comment: Yes! Exactly this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'correct' choice of the solution space has to fulfill two basic requirements:

- It must be complete (and typically, reflexive) space such that you can get good existence results.
- Weak and strong solutions should (up to regularity issues) coincide.

It is clear that the first point is satisfied by $V = H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Now, let $\phi$ be strong / classical solution with regularity $\phi \in C^4(\bar\Omega)$ and it satisfies the equations in a pointwise way. Then, it is clear that $\phi \in V$.
For an arbitrary $v \in V$, we have
$$
\int_\Omega -\Delta \phi \cdot v \, \mathrm{d}x
=
\int_\Omega \nabla\phi \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x
-
\int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n} \cdot \underbrace{v}_{=0} \, \mathrm{d}s
$$
and
$$
\int_\Omega \Delta^2 \phi \cdot v \, \mathrm{d}x
=
\int_\Omega \Delta \phi \cdot \Delta v \, \mathrm{d}x
+
\int_{\partial\Omega}
 \frac{\partial\Delta\phi}{\partial n} \cdot \underbrace{v}_{=0}
-
 \frac{\partial v}{\partial n} \cdot \underbrace{\Delta \phi}_{=0}
 \, \mathrm{d}s.
$$
By adding these identities you can plug in the right-hand side of your PDE and arrive at the weak formulation.
(Note that this process is very similar to the incorporation of a (natural) Neumann boundary condition for Poisson's equation)

Along the same lines one can show that a weak solution with enough regularity is also a strong solution.

Comment: Why $v=0$ on the right-hand side of the equation? And you use the Green's Identiie to obtain the second equation?

Comment: Because $v \in V = H^2 \cap H_0^1$ and functions from $H_0^1$ vanish on the boundary.

Comment: Yes, the second equation is Green's identity applied to $\Delta \phi$ and $v$.

Comment: Thank you so much!